# How do I append multiple ids with getElementById to email with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, email, submit-button

I have a web form with 5 different text areas to collect data (id's ta1, ta2, ta3, ta4, ta5). What I'd like to do is get all the data submitted in an email when I click the button.

Here's my code. I'm able to get the one text area, but not the others. Can someone help?

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href=&quot;mailto:info@email.com?subject=Feedback&body=&quot;+document.getElementById(&quot;ta1&quot;).value;" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Maybe putting the javascript between `<script>` tags would help with legibility.

Comment: Yes, start by putting your javascript in a separate function between `<script>` tags. And look up what a `+` does to javascript strings.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways. One obvious way can be to make a java script function. Make string of all desired tag value and pass it to mail body.Simply Call function on onClick action.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a unique id to each textarea, assign them a common name and then get all the inputs by calling
`texts = getElementsByName('common_name')`
You can then iterate over texts to get values of all the textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions! This seemed to work well for me, except now I'm finding there's a character limit for this option below. Does anyone know how to increase that limit??

```js
  function emailForm(href) {
    var subject = "This form data";
    var body = "Notes:\r\n\r\n";
    body += "<ta1>\r\n";
    body += document.getElementById("ta1").value;
    body += "\r\n\r\n<ta2>\r\n";
    body += document.getElementById("ta2").value;
    body += "\r\n\r\n<ta3>\r\n";
    body += document.getElementById("ta3").value;
    body += "\r\n\r\n<ta4>\r\n";
    body += document.getElementById("ta4").value;
    body += "\r\n\r\n<ta5>\r\n";
    body += document.getElementById("ta5").value;
    body += "\r\n\r\n";
    var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
    uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
    uri += "&body=";
    uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
    window.open(uri);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Send form data in an email</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
  <textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
  <textarea id="ta3"></textarea>
  <textarea id="ta4"></textarea>
  <textarea id="ta5"></textarea>

  <input type="button" onclick="emailForm();" value="Submit">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now it looks like I'm running into a different issue. There seems to be a max character limit for sending the form this way. Does anyone know how to get around that?